# How can we avoid the blank/empty page in report when the report has no data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

When my selected parameter has no data, how to avoid those blank or empty pages while subscription.

Detailing:

I have used 3 parameters in my report if one the parameter doesn't have any data the report will give a blank. In subscription, I want to avoid those empty or blank pages in the report. Is there any alternate solution available to avoid this scenario.

Need report only with data by avoiding existing blank or empty pages in the report.

Comment: are you using data driven subscription or standard subscription?

Comment: its Data driven subscription but I couldn't achieve it, Is there any other way to restrict blank pages in report level.

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to stop blank pages to go out when data is not available for Data Driven subscriptions.

In your **data set for the subscription**, wrap an if statement to check for data.. if nothing.. raise an error and be done.. else return the data set with data appropriate for the subscription.

like this :

```
if not exists(
select top 1
yourtable.columns

 from yourtable

-- the rest of your dataset conditions do here!

)


raiserror ('No report to be generated!',16,1)
else

select 
yourtable.columns

 from yourtable

-- the rest of your dataset conditions do here!
```

The rest of the subscription stays the same. You will see, if there is no data.. the subscription runs but will return your error and nothing else will happen.. if there is data, then the subscription will deliver as expected.